# Customising Silverlight AutoCompleteBox with multiple filtered ListBoxes

Tags: silverlight, listbox, silverlight-4.0, autocompletebox

How should I go about customising the AutoCompleteBox in Silverlight so that while typing I can filter multiple Selector ListBoxes. Basically I want a Popup that contains 'n' ListBoxes vertically stacked and when I type, the filtering operates on all of them simultaneously. I can then select an item from any of the ListBoxes.

Thanks in advance for any guidance you may have.

Beks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to go with a custom control in the end, inheriting from Control. The control I created contains a textbox and popup that contains multiple listboxes that are updated as i type in the text box.